# T4 Text Templates: method to return html expression

Tags: c#, t4

I have the following T4 text template and it is repeated in many places:

```
<# if (!package.Name.Equals("Amazon")) {#>
    <td><#=package.Name#></td>
<#} else {#>
    <td><a href="<#=package.Name#>@Amazon.com"><#=package.Name#></a></td>
<#}#>
```

I want to replace this with a function that returns string with href attribute if the package.Name equals Amazon, for example:

```
 private static string ConvertPackageName(Package package)
 {
    if (!package.Name.Equals("Amazon"))
    {
       return package.Name;
    }

    return "<a href="<#=package.Name#>@Amazon.com"><#=package.Name#></a>";
 }
```

is it possible to have something like this so I can have a code like this instead:

```
<td><#=ConvertPackageName(package)#></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [class feature blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126541.aspx): `<#+ /* code */ #>`

Answer (score 1):

As Athari said, you need to use [class feature blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126541.aspx).  There are a few gotchas that you need to know about for them to work well though.

1. All statement blocks (`<# #>`) within feature blocks must be changed to feature blocks.  This means that anywhere you would normally use a `<# #>` tag, you now use a `<#+ #>` tag.  `<#= #>` tags still work normally.
2. You cannot have any statement blocks after your first feature block.  For this reason, you will need to place your function at the end of the template file.

Here is an example of how your code could look:

```
Some template code....
<# ConvertPackageName(package); #>
More template code...
<# ConvertPackageName(package); #>
....

<#+ void ConvertPackageName(Package package) { #>
    <#+ if (!package.Name.Equals("Amazon")) {#>
        <td><#=package.Name#></td>
    <#+} else {#>
        <td><a href="<#=package.Name#>@Amazon.com"><#=package.Name#></a></td>
    <#+}#>
<#+}#>
END OF TEMPLATE
```

The text generated within ConvertPackageName will be injected wherever you call the method from, so in your example you would have template code that looks like `<td><# ConvertPackageName(package); #></td>`